# How to check if rake task was finished?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rake

This is my first experience with RoR and I using the rspec tool to test my controller. But inside the methods, I using rake tasks to create asynchronous solutions like this:

```
 def scan_all_urls
   system 'rake scan_all_urls &'
 end
```

And my rake task is this:

```
 task :scan_all_urls => :environment do
   crawler = Crawler.new
   urls = Url.all
   crawler.scan_urls(urls)
 end
```

But my issue is, at the rspec test:

```
it 'should scan all url' do
    params = {}
    get 'scan_all_urls', params: params, format: :json
end
```

How I could set to wait until the rake task finish?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really check that rake task finished. I would suggest to you write good specs for `Crawler#scan_urls` and maybe check in the controller that `Crawler` was called.

Also, test returning values in your controller spec. So the controller spec might look like this

```
it 'should scan all url' do
    expect(Crawler).to receive(:new).and_call_original

    params = {}
    get 'scan_all_urls', params: params, format: :json

    expect(MultiJson.load response.body).to # something
end
```